# How is the linking mechanism so fast in the kernel system calls?

Tags: linux-kernel, make, gcc

If I open any file in Linux kernel almost every file has many extern functions and many `#indef` or `#ifndef` macros so while compiling how exactly does it map all the functions and macros when more than 70 included header files inside a `.c/.h` file?

How exactly and how fast does it do this task? And is GCC only responsible for these things or is there some other program which does all these tasks?

Comment: This question is not about Linux, and it is probably off topic. I do not believe it is poorly written and researched so much as lacking basic understanding. It needs to migrate elsewhere, but I want to get this kid a chance to learn.

Comment: This question is too broad, you're basically asking "how does a C compiler and linker work?". 70 headers isn't that much by the way. Any non-trivial C code will source a lot of headers (simple hello world gets 16 on my system, including OpenSSL results in 76).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, to fully answer your question, you need to read a book on introductory programing in C and [Tanenbaum](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131429388) and [the dragon book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools). Start with learning C.

Some of the basic pieces to get you started: when compiling a C program there are traditionally several distinct phases. (modern compilers may do cross phase optimization) These phases are:

1. prepossessor. This deals with include files, #ifdef, #define and macro expansion.
2. compiler. This converts C code to a more machine level intermediate representation (sometimes assembler).
3. assembler. This converts the intermediate representation to actual machine code.
4. linker. This puts all the pieces together and deals with memory issues. There may be more than one link pass.

gcc can do all of the above, but as the kernel is complicated there are other tools used, most of which are kernel specific.

Now the kernel in some ways is just another program, but it has many differences including syscalls, which vary depending on hardware.

On a typical Linux program when you ask the kernel to do something like open a file

1. Your program calls a library function,
2. the library function makes a syscall,
3. the kernel looks up the syscall in a dispatch table,
4. the kernel does authentication checks,
5. the kernel does the work,
6. the kernel returns the result to the library function,
7. the library function returns the result to your program.

This can take place many hundreds of times per second.